# Get facebook friends posts using graph API

Tags: facebook, graph, posts

I am trying to build an application which requires access to friend's feed posts. Is it possible to retrieve friend's wall posts using graph API? I checked out in the developer console and found no such funstionality. If possible can someone explain me how do i go about retrieving it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

friend permissions are gone, and `read_stream` [will not get approved](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream) by Facebook unless you are building an App for a platform without a native Facebook client. So there is no way to get access to friend walls - unless they authorize your App too. You can use `user_posts` for that.

You can read more about all the changes in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Facebook improved privacy for users, that´s why you can´t get any details of users who did not authorize your App.

Comment: Thanks mate!! Is there any way around? Like using user_posts for web app to fetch the data?

Comment: Also the changelog states " The user_posts permission is automatically granted to anyone who previously had read_stream permission'. Can you please clarify on this part if possible?

Comment: there is no way around, you can ONLY get data from users who authorized your app. forget about that other part, read_stream will not get approved anyway. main point is: you can only get stuff that is happening on the wall of the authorized user.

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking is no longer supported by Facebook.

Read [this article](http://jobfusion.co/blog/no-more-referrals-fb-friends-api-shutting-down-april-30) by one of the apps that were affected by so.

Sorry for not helping you more.

Comment: thanks mate!! Actually I am building a web application, fbstart seems to be a mobile app accelerator program. Is there anything which you know that would suffice my requirement?

Comment: even WITH paying it is no longer supported. not sure where you got the idea that you could pay for it...

Comment: @luschn Oh!! Isn't there a way around? Because the very idea of my application revolves around this functionality of fetching my friend's facebook posts?

Comment: no, there is no way around. you are not supposed to get access to the wall of users who did not even authorize your app.

Comment: You seem to be correct i've no idea where i came with the paid option