# can I get what friends are sharing on their profile via facebook Graph API

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My question is very simple but there is nothing on google regarding that. When I use facebook if I go to the profile of my friend I can see his posts which he has allowed me to see. So my question is that can I get data on my friends profile? Of Course only the one he has allowed me to see, using facebook graph API.

Comment: I don't think Facebook allows this anymore. See: [Get facebook friends posts using graph API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035703/get-facebook-friends-posts-using-graph-api).

Comment: If your friend grants the app user_posts permission then you can get his posts. Otherwise no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has made a lot of changes in its API to reduce abuses. As you can see in [2.3 changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3), the new permission is `user_posts`, but it will allow you to see user posts, and not those of his friends. If Facebook disallows it, it's a waste of time to search more...

Comment: So if my app is fully dependent on this feature I might have to rethink the idea. Great thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: You can still use this feature if your users' friends have also logged into your app. But it can be a big drawback...